# Maven configuration for using Dagger 2 in a mixed Java/Kotlin project

Tags: java, maven, kotlin, dagger-2

What is the recommended Maven setup for using [Dagger 2](https://github.com/google/dagger) in a mixed Java/Kotlin project?

I found a sample project which uses Gradle: https://github.com/damianpetla/kotlin-dagger-example
Something similar with Maven would be very helpful.

---

**UPDATE: What have I tried?**

I used the Kotlin configuration from [kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-maven.html](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-maven.html)
and the Dagger configuration from [google.github.io/dagger](http://google.github.io/dagger).
I also used the [build-helper-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/) plugin to integrate the annotation processing in IDEA.

My main problem was that I run into compilation cycles. My configuration mixed the compilation of Kotlin and calling the annotation processor, which generates Dagger2 classes. I unsystematically tried to separate both phases but lacked the deeper Maven understanding to get it working.

Answer (score 3):

javac can scan both source files (java) and classes in search for annotations:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#processing

This means that you can make this work if you don't have any Dagger-generated classes referenced in Kotlin code (which means Dagger module implementations)

1. invoke kotlin compiler (no Dagger generated types in Kotlin code)
2. invoke annotation processor (processes annotations in both java files and kotlin-compiled files)
3. invoke java compiler - has access to both Dagger generated types and Kotlin types

You can write your services in both java and kotlin, but the module must be created by a java class

Here is the corresponding pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>testkotlindagger</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <kotlin.version>1.0.6</kotlin.version>
        <dagger2.version>2.7</dagger2.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Dagger 2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>dagger</artifactId>
            <version>${dagger2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>dagger-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>${dagger2.version}</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals> <goal>compile</goal> </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <source>src/main/java</source>
                                <source>src/main/kotlin</source>

                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals> <goal>test-compile</goal> </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>process</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/annotations</outputDirectory>

                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Replacing default-compile as it is treated specially by maven -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-compile</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Replacing default-testCompile as it is treated specially by maven -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-testCompile</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>java-compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals> <goal>compile</goal> </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>java-test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals> <goal>testCompile</goal> </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

On the other hand, if you include Dagger-generated types in your kotlin code, you must have these available before kotlin code is compiled, which means you need Kotlin-aware annotation processor (KAPT)

In this scenario the problem boils down to the question:
[Is kapt supported in maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39531333/is-kapt-supported-in-maven)

Sadly, the answer is no, but there is a bug filed to support it:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-14478

Comment: fyi KT-14478 has been fixed and thus kapt is now supported in maven

Answer (score 0):

Since kapt is now supported in maven, you can write your services in both Java and Kotlin, and the module can be created by either a Java class or a Kotlin class. You can configure pom.xml build file like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.20</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>dagger</artifactId>
        <version>2.22</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>kapt</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>kapt</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirs>
                            <sourceDir>src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            <sourceDir>src/main/java</sourceDir>
                        </sourceDirs>
                        <annotationProcessorPaths>
                            <!-- Specify your annotation processors here. -->
                            <annotationProcessorPath>
                                <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
                                <artifactId>dagger-compiler</artifactId>
                                <version>2.22</version>
                            </annotationProcessorPath>
                        </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirs>
                            <sourceDir>src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            <sourceDir>src/main/java</sourceDir>
                        </sourceDirs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirs>
                            <sourceDir>src/test/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            <sourceDir>src/test/java</sourceDir>
                        </sourceDirs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-compile</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-testCompile</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>java-compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>java-test-compile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

These are the links usefull to read when you want to create maven project with java, kotlin and dagger:

- https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/maven-java-project
- https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kapt.html#using-in-maven
- https://github.com/google/dagger#installation

Please note that kapt is still not supported for IntelliJ IDEA's own build system. Because of this, you will not be able to compile and run the application in the Intellij IDE by clicking on the Play button next to the Main method. To run the application, first build the project using the maven toolbox. After that, you can run the application in the Intellij IDE by clicking on the Play button next to the Main method. Alternatively you can create a run configuration to run the jar file. After that, you can run this configuration, or run it in debug mode by clicking on the run or debug button next to the run configuration combobox.