# Is kapt supported in maven?

Tags: maven, kotlin, kapt

Is it possible to run kapt (kotlin annotation processing) in a maven based project?

If yes how do I integrate kapt in maven build system?

Comment: Yes you can. You need to add `kotlin-maven-plugin`

Comment: @Bikku that is not correct, it does not support APT

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Kotlin 1.1.2 there is now support for both Gradle and Maven to run the KAPT plugins.  This is documented in [Using Kotlin annotation processing tool](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html) where it says to:

> Add an execution of the kapt goal from kotlin-maven-plugin before compile:

```
<execution>
    <id>kapt</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>kapt</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <sourceDirs>
            <sourceDir>src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
            <sourceDir>src/main/java</sourceDir>
        </sourceDirs>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <!-- Specify your annotation processors here. -->
            <annotationProcessorPath>
                <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
                <artifactId>dagger-compiler</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
            </annotationProcessorPath>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

Comment: Is this still true? There seem to be `<goal>kapt</goal>` within `kotlin-maven-plugin` - described here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html