# kapt is not working even manually in IntelliJ with Maven

Tags: maven, kotlin, intellij-idea

https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/master/mapstruct-kotlin

I run above kotlin mapstruct project with maven but it emits below error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find implementation for org.mapstruct.example.kotlin.converter.PersonConverter
    at org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers.getMapper(Mappers.java:61)
    at org.mapstruct.example.kotlin.MainKt.main(Main.kt:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find implementation for org.mapstruct.example.kotlin.converter.PersonConverter
    at org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers.getMapper(Mappers.java:75)
    at org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers.getMapper(Mappers.java:58)
    ... 1 more
```

[image]
It seems annotation processor is not working even I enabled annotation processing in the `Settings`.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kapt.html#using-in-cli
The Official kotlin document says:

> Please note that kapt is still not supported for IntelliJ IDEA’s own build system. Launch the build from the “Maven Projects” toolbar whenever you want to re-run the annotation processing.

(related issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-15040)

So I tried to conduct `kapt` manually.
[image]

However the output folders are still empty.

[image]

What's wrong with me?
I was able to do annotation processing in Java with Maven before.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

Just push `compile` button in `Maven project` or `mvn compile` in command
before running your application whenever you need the annotation processing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an excerpt from my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74040187/216479) to similar question:
You can configure pom.xml build file like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.20</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>dagger</artifactId>
        <version>2.22</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>kapt</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>kapt</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirs>
                            <sourceDir>src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            <sourceDir>src/main/java</sourceDir>
                        </sourceDirs>
                        <annotationProcessorPaths>
                            <!-- Specify your annotation processors here. -->
                            <annotationProcessorPath>
                                <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
                                <artifactId>dagger-compiler</artifactId>
                                <version>2.22</version>
                            </annotationProcessorPath>
                        </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirs>
                            <sourceDir>src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            <sourceDir>src/main/java</sourceDir>
                        </sourceDirs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirs>
                            <sourceDir>src/test/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            <sourceDir>src/test/java</sourceDir>
                        </sourceDirs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-compile</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-testCompile</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>java-compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>java-test-compile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

These are the links usefull to read when you want to create maven project with java, kotlin and dagger:

- https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/maven-java-project
- https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kapt.html#using-in-maven
- https://github.com/google/dagger#installation