# Using kapt in maven

Tags: maven, kotlin, dagger, kapt

I'm trying to make a small application for my asignment in kotlin using dagger and maven (can't switch to gradle) and  I'm aware that for kotlin, i need to add not only dagger but also the kapt for it to work. Here is where my problem starts, it doesn't work.

I've being for the last 2 days searching arround the internet for any kind of information on this and the only thing related to kapt and maven I've found is on the jetbrains site where they say that i have to add an execution block to my pom. Well so I've done this and it still doesn't work. I get a "cannot resolve symbol" in the goal kapt.

I suspect the problem is either one of this:

1. I may be missing a dependency.
2. I'm placing the execution block for the kapt in the wrong place.

Here is my pom.xml:

`

4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>MyAnimeList</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>MyAnimeList</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <junit.version>5.8.2</junit.version>
    <kotlin.version>1.6.21</kotlin.version>
    <koin.version>3.1.6</koin.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.insert-koin/koin-core -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.insert-koin</groupId>
        <artifactId>koin-core-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>${koin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.insert-koin/koin-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.insert-koin</groupId>
        <artifactId>koin-test-junit5</artifactId>
        <version>${koin.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.insert-koin</groupId>
        <artifactId>koin-test-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>${koin.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>17.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>17.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
        <version>11.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kordamp.bootstrapfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrapfx-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- sqlite-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.36.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- logger -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Lombok -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.24</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- MyBatis -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Gson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Dagger -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>dagger</artifactId>
        <version>2.41</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>dagger-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>2.41</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirs>
                            <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDir>
                        </sourceDirs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirs>
                            <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</sourceDir>
                        </sourceDirs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
                        <artifactId>dagger-compiler</artifactId>
                        <version>2.41</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>1.18.22</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <!-- Replacing default-compile as it is treated specially by maven -->
               
                <execution>
                    <id>default-compile</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
                <!-- Replacing default-testCompile as it is treated specially by maven -->
                <execution>
                    <id>default-testCompile</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>java-compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>java-test-compile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M6</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                    <id>default-cli</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>com.example.myanimelist/com.example.myanimelist.HelloApplication</mainClass>
                        <launcher>app</launcher>
                        <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                        <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                        <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                        <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                        <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

`

It may be a simple solution but I'm still not fluent with all this dagger/kotlin stuff so thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an excerpt from my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74040187/216479) to similar question:
You can configure pom.xml build file like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.20</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>dagger</artifactId>
        <version>2.22</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>kapt</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>kapt</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirs>
                            <sourceDir>src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            <sourceDir>src/main/java</sourceDir>
                        </sourceDirs>
                        <annotationProcessorPaths>
                            <!-- Specify your annotation processors here. -->
                            <annotationProcessorPath>
                                <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
                                <artifactId>dagger-compiler</artifactId>
                                <version>2.22</version>
                            </annotationProcessorPath>
                        </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirs>
                            <sourceDir>src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            <sourceDir>src/main/java</sourceDir>
                        </sourceDirs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirs>
                            <sourceDir>src/test/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            <sourceDir>src/test/java</sourceDir>
                        </sourceDirs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-compile</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-testCompile</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>java-compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>java-test-compile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

These are the links usefull to read when you want to create maven project with java, kotlin and dagger:

- https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/maven-java-project
- https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kapt.html#using-in-maven
- https://github.com/google/dagger#installation